# jQuery not focusing the correct DOM element

Tags: jquery

I have 3 buttons setup and whenever tab is clicked the 3rd button should be focuses rather than the next one in the row which is the first button. For some reason I can't get the following code to work. Any ideas as to why it's not working?

```
$("#updater").keyup(function(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if(keyCode === 9) {
        $("#shareButton").focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning `false` to prevent the default action

```
$("#updater").keyup(function(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if(keyCode === 9) {
        $("#shareButton").focus();
        return false;  // <- add this
    }
});
```

alternativly you can also do [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) instead of `return false;`

EDIT:

Ok try changing `keyup` to `keydown`

### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UDrWX/)

Comment: The two are not the same. `return false` also stops event bubbling.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby: Did you try it in more than one browser?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested yet, But I think this should work.

```
 $("#updater").bind("keydown",function(event) {
     if (event.which == 9) {
      e.preventDefault();
       $("#shareButton").focus();
       }
    });
```